# Error: Sys.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: clientObject

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I'm trying to get list count from my custom list for current user. But the error: ***("Error: Sys.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null***. **Parameter name: clientObject")** is being thrown. First part of the code where i have to get properties of current user works fine. I think `PopulateEmployeeHeader(currentUser)` is causing the error.

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    // Ensure that the SP.UserProfiles.js file is loaded before the custom code runs.
    SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(loadUserData, 'SP.UserProfiles.js'); 
    $('#errorBase').hide();  
  });
  var userProfileProperties;
  var user;
  function loadUserData(){

    //Get Current Context   
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    //Get Instance of People Manager Class
    var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);

    //Get properties of the current user
    userProfileProperties = peopleManager.getMyProperties()

    clientContext.load(userProfileProperties);

    //Execute the Query.
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFail);

  }

  function onSuccess() { 

    var employeePhoto =userProfileProperties.get_pictureUrl();
    PopulateEmployeeHeader(userProfileProperties.get_displayName());

    if(employeePhoto !== undefined && employeePhoto !== "" && employeePhoto !== null)
    {
        $('#employeePicture').attr('src', userProfileProperties.get_pictureUrl());
        }
        else
        { 
        $('results').innerHTML = "Picture does not exist in User Profiles list. Please upload your picture.";       
        }  
    }  
  function onFail(sender, args) {
    alert("Error: " + args.get_message());
  }

var oEmployee;
function PopulateEmployeeHeader(currentUser)
{   
//  var queryListItem = '<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="j2ur"/><Value Type="User">'+currentUser+'</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>';
    var queryListItem='<View><Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name="j2ur" />'+currentUser+'</Eq><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name="j2ur" />'+
    +'</IsNotNull></And></Where></Query></View>';
        var siteUrl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host+'/';
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oEmployees = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Accounts');

    var myquery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    myquery.set_viewXml(queryListItem);
    this.oEmployee= oEmployees.getItems(myquery);

    clientContext.load(oEmployee);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onEmployeeSucceeded),
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onEmployeeFailed)
 );
}

function onEmployeeSucceeded(sender, args) {

alert(oEmployee.get_count());
}

function onEmployeeFailed(sender, args) {

 alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +'\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

})(jQuery);
```